# Compare date with each value of mysql json array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Mysql 5.7

Mysql JSON array contains a list of dates in `specific_dates` field of TABLE as given below:

[image]

I want to compare(>=) all the above dates with the given date. I've tried the below query in laravel but not working.

```
->whereRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(`specific_dates`, "$[*]") >= ?', $value);
```

Here, `$value` would be `yyyy-mm-dd` format. `e.g. 2020-04-02`.

It should return if the `$value` is equal or less than any value of JSON array.
Thanks

Comment: provide some code and json

Comment: there nothing more than the above-given code. which code/json do you want?

Comment: I am stuck with exact same issue , have you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
->where(function ($query) use($value) {
     $query->whereRaw("find_in_set('" . $value . "',specific_dates)");   
});
```

Comment: Not working, bcs i want to compare greater/less (>= OR <=) with `$value`.